# Why I can't pull a image to dependency proxy from GitLab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-in-docker, gitlab-ci.yml, docker-pull

I've tried pull a image to dependency proxy from GitLab, I've read the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:19.03.12

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

build:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $TOKEN_USERNAME -p $TOKEN_PASSWORD $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_SERVER
  script:
    -  docker pull ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/php:7-fpm-alpine3.15
```

I've used a token created in my group but in console show that error

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Answer (score 1):

Are `$TOKEN_USERNAME` and `$TOKEN_PASSWORD` defined? The documentation says to use the predefined variables `$CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_USER` and `$CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_PASSWORD`.

```bash
docker login -u $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_USER -p $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_PASSWORD $CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_SERVER
```